# A bug in java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, unicode, java.util.scanner

java.util.Scanner can't handle non-breaking spaces in file content which is bizarre.

Here is the input text, put this in a file called `asdf.txt`:

```
lines lines lines
asdf jkl
lines lines lines
```

Between `asdf` and `jkl` is a non breaking space.  Specifically:

```
echo "asdf jkl" | od -c
0000000   a   s   d   f 302 240   j   k   l  \n
0000012
```

You can copy/paste it in here and see it: http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/analyzer/

The offending character is also known as: `302 240`,  `U+00A0`, `&nbsp;`, `&#160;`, `&#x00A0;`, `%C2%A0`

The code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner r = null;
        try{
            File f = new File("/home2/ericlesc/testfile/asdf.txt");
            r = new Scanner(f);
            while(r.hasNextLine()){
                String line = r.nextLine();
                System.out.println("line is: " + line);
            }   
            System.out.println("done");
        }   
        catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```

java.util.Scanner pukes on this content.  Surprisingly, it does NOT throw an exception saying "can't process this character".  It doesn't stop on the offending line, the Scanner pukes roughly 30 characters before the offending character.

Maybe there is known documentation on how I can use java.util.Scanner to read in a non breaking space without puking?

Why can't java.util.Scanner process non breaking space?  How can I make it process it as normal?

Comment: from java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by Character.isWhitespace. The reset() method will reset the value of the scanner's delimiter to the default whitespace delimiter regardless of whether it was previously changed.

Comment: Non breaking space unicode character seems to cause java.util.Scanner to treat it as neither a whitespace character nor a normal character.  It causes Scanner to crash, and it gives up, and Scanner says there are no more lines in the file.  It's as if the unicode character is interpreted as an "end of file" and it just quits thinking everything is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you tell it otherwise, Scanner assumes the system's default charset.  I'm not sure about other OSes, but on Windows, this is one of the ISO 8859 charsets for compatibility reasons.

Luckily, you can tell `Scanner` what `CharSet` you want it to use by using one of the 2 argument constructors like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-java.lang.String-).

Comment: On my work PC (windows 7), the `Charset.defaultCharset()` is `UTF-8`, which breaks as per the OP's example.  If I create my `Scanner` as `new Scanner(f, "ISO-8859-1");` the line with the non-breaking space prints normally.

Answer (score 0):

With help from powerlord, I was able to use this code to produce the desired output:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner r = null;
        try{
            File f = new File("/home2/ericlesc/testfile/asdf.txt");
            r = new Scanner(f, "ISO-8859-1");
            while(r.hasNextLine()){
                String line = r.nextLine();
                System.out.println("line is: " + line);
            }   
            System.out.println("done");
        }   
        catch(Exception e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }   
}
```

Program prints:

```
javac Main.java && java Main

line is: lines lines lines
line is: asdf jkl
line is: lines lines lines
```

You have to specify the same charset that was used to encode the characters, else Scanner will exhibit undefined behavior when it encounters a character it does not understand.